# PHP parse some code from html

Tags: php, html, parsing, rss

I'm having difficulty in parsing Google News RSS with PHP. The XML description contains lots of mess, I need only 2 small parts from it, but i dont know how can i extract only my desired parts. I have been trying to get with PHP preg_macth, but i didnt get success.

Please see the following code, i have added comment in the text which parts i'm trying to get.

PS. Sorry this look little messed but thats how the google news rss is:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top;">
<tr>
<td width="80" align="center" valign="top">
<font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif">
    <a href="http://">
    <!-- i need only this img src only -->
    <img src="http://nt3.ggpht.com/news/tbn/ExvkIyaCiPpZwM/6.jpg" /><br />
    <!-- /till here -->
    <font size="-2">Moneycontrol.com</font></a>
</font>
</td>

<td valign="top" class="j"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><br />

<div style="padding-top:0.8em;">
<img alt="" height="1" width="1" /></div>
<div class="lh">

    <a href="http://">
    <b>Microsoft&#39;s Office 365 to take on Google Apps in cloud software race</b>
    </a><br />

<font size="-1">
    <b><font color="#6f6f6f">Los Angeles Times</font></b>
</font><br />

<font size="-1">
<!----------------- i need only the following text ----------->
Microsoft Corp., the 800-pound gorilla of the software world, is hoping it can lift itself into the cloud. In announcing the general release of Office 365, the online version of its ubiquitous Microsoft Office suite that includes Word, <b>...</b>
<!------------------------- -till here ------------------>
</font><br />

<font size="-1">
    <a href="http://">Office 365: Microsoft Pitches Cloud, Eyes Profit</a>
    <font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f"><nobr>InformationWeek</nobr></font>
</font>
<br />

<font size="-1">
    <a href="http://">Microsoft Battles for Sky Supremacy With Office 365 Launch</a>
    <font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f"><nobr>TechNewsWorld</nobr></font>
</font><br />
...
```

Really thanks for your valuable time reading this, and helping me.

Comment: As usual, do NOT parse html (or even xml) with regex. Use DOM.

Comment: this isnt xml, maybe this is CDATA, anyway you could try http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmliterator.php

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help, but you can take a look into the PHP function "strip_tags"

Comment: Parsing isnt stripping, strip_tag removes most html tags.

Comment: I know.. but he needs the text inside the HTML. he can strip the tags and then parse a much simpler result

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strip_tags_ex function I wrote the other day (just yesterday, actually). It allows you to specify tags of which the whole content should be stripped. It also allows specifying tags of which the attributes should be kept in the resulting text.

It may not do exactly what you want, but it at least shows you how to traverse a DOM tree and check each elements tag and attributes.

Sorry about the comments being in Dutch. Code is reasonably self-explanatory though.

```
<?php

/**
 * Helper function. Extraheert recursief tekst uit een DOMNode, met inachtneming van de opgegeven regels.
 */
function extract_text_from_node(DOMNode $node, &$index_attrs, &$remove_elements, array &$output)
{
    if ($node->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE)
    {
        // Huidige node is een tekstnode. Tekst outputten.
        $output[] = $node->data;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($node->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
            // Huidige node is een element. Speciale behandeling;

            if (array_search($node->tagName, $remove_elements) !== false)
            {
                // Element staat in de lijst met uitzonderingen. Verder negeren.
                return;
            }

            if (array_key_exists($node->tagName, $index_attrs))
            {
                // Element staat in de lijst van tags waarvan ook attributen geëxporteerd moeten worden.
                $prefixed = false;
                // Voor elk opgegeven attribuut controleren of het bestaat.
                foreach($index_attrs[$node->tagName] as $attribute)
                {
                    $value = $node->getAttribute($attribute);
                    if ($value !== '')
                    {
                        // Attribuut gevonden. Outputten.

                        // Sommige tags voorzien van extra prefex, zodat de tekst van de attributen
                        // wat meer context krijgt in de uiteindelijke platte tekst.
                        if ($prefixed === false)
                        {
                            switch ($node->tagName)
                            {
                                case 'img': $output[] = 'Afbeelding: '; break;
                                case 'a': $output[] = 'Link: '; break;
                                default: break;
                            }
                            $prefixed = true;
                        }
                        // Attribute teruggeven met spaties er omheen.
                        $output[] = ' '.$value.' ';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Willekeurige node. Als ie children heeft, dan recursief aanroepen.
        $child = $node->firstChild;
        while ($child)
        {
            extract_text_from_node($child, $index_attrs, $remove_elements, $output);
            $child = $child->nextSibling;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * strip_tags_ex extraheert tekst uit een html string.
 * @param string $string. De HTML code om in te zoeken
 * @param array $index_attrs. De elementen waarvan attributen ook teruggegeven moeten worden.
 * In de vorm array(tag=>array(attribute,...),...)
 * $param array of string $remove_elements. Array van elementen die helemaal, inclusief inhoud, genegeerd moeten worden.
 */
function strip_tags_ex($string, $index_attrs, $remove_elements)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    // Eventuele warning (die ontstaan bij ongeldige HTML) onderdrukken.
    @$dom->loadHTML($string);

    $output = array();

    $root = $dom->documentElement;

    // Tekst uit rootnode extraheren.
    extract_text_from_node($root, $index_attrs, $remove_elements, $output);

    // Resultaat-array samenvoegen tot een string.
    return implode('', $output);
}

$string = 'Hallo wereld';
echo strip_tags_ex(
    $string,
    array(
        'a'=>array('alt', 'title'),
        'img'=>array('alt')),
    array('div'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the img src using http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmliterator.php as stated earlier; however, retrieving that specific line of text from the feed seems finicky. There doesn't appear to be any unique identifier to that "description".